# Using Google to scrape population figures in R

Tags: html, r, xpath, html-parsing, rcurl

I want to search, for example, "Population Apollo Beach, FL" and extract the population figure returned by Google.  In this example, Google even shows the "quick view" at the top and includes the year of the statistic.

How can I scrape this result and year?

I am currently trying this with the `RCurl` and `XML` packages, but I am not having luck extracting the right HTML node.  I inspected the element in chrome and copied the xpath:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

search.term="population Apollo Beach"

site <- getForm("http://www.google.com/search",hl="en",lr="",q=search.term,btnG="Search")
text <- htmlParse(site)

xpathApply(text,'//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]')
```

1)  Is this legal based on Google's TOS?

2)  How can I extract the correct xpath node?

Comment: Personally, I think you'll have a much easier job if you scrap those pieces of information from Wikipedia.

Comment: for "Is this legal based on Google's TOS" - have you read their TOS?

Comment: @RicardoFernandesCampos it seems like Wikipedia doesn't always have the data, so that's why I am using Google

Comment: @SymbolixAU Yes, I have, but the key is whether this is "permitted by the content owner".   For example, it seems clear that Wikipedia would be OK.  But, I also have trouble wrapping my head around the idea that 2010 public census data is not free and clear to scrape...Thoughts?

Comment: From memory, as part of Google's TOS they don't let you scrape their website. As it's publicly available census data you're after, there [must be other sources you can try](https://www.census.gov/2010census/data/) without having to scrape a website?

Comment: @SymbolixAU Yes, I can absolutely any source.  Unfortunately, I am trying to get population figures for every US city, and I am having a hard time finding 1 dataset with all the info.  The census site itself has a series of zip folders for each state.  I guess I'll just have to go the route of downloading zip folder, unzipping, etc.

Comment: maybe look at [library censusapi](https://github.com/hrecht/censusapi) ?

Comment: @SymbolixAU Awesome, I'll check that out.  For now, I also finally found this page, which gives me all the population figures in 1 table!